# Get emit value from specific V-for element

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, v-for, emit

I'm trying to get ID from specific element. But the data is returning as many elements as there are and all are same value. Even if I click another element button, the value was unchanged.[The output Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PqnP.png)
How I resolve this?

Here parent component code:

```
<template>
        <ProductsList
          class="w-full"
          :product="item"
          @product-id="selectedID"
          v-for="(item, idx) in products"
          :key="idx"
        />
</template>
<script>
export default {
  async asyncData(context) {
    const products = await context.app
      .$axios({
        method: "get",
        url: process.env.PROJECT_API + "/products",
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${context.store.state.currentToken}`,
        },
      })
      .then((res) => res.data.products);
    return {
      products,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    selectedID(id) {
      this.products.find( el => {
        el._id === id
        console.log({id});
      })
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

The child component code:

```
<template> 
 <button @click="passId">
   details
 <button>
<template> 

export default {
    props: ['product'],
    methods: {
      passId() {
        this.$emit('product-id', this.product._id)
      }
    },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `selectedID` method assigns the searched `id` to every product.

[find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) returns the first item for which the checked condition is `true`.
Your `find()` doesn't check anything. Instead, it assigns the `id` to each element (you're using `=` instead of `===`), without returning anything, which technically means it returns `undefined`, which evaluates to `false` for each item. So your `.find()` doesn't find anything.

In other words, you have to replace

```
selectedID(id) {
  this.products.find( el => {
    el._id = id
    console.log({id});
  })
}
```

with:

```
selectedID(id) {
  console.log(this.products.find(el => el._id === id)?._id);
}
```

or, more explicitly:

```
selectedID(id) {
  const product = this.products.find(el => el._id === id);
  if (product) {
    console.log(product._id);
  }
}
```

In the above find, `el => el._id === id` is shorthand for:

```
function(el) {
  return el._id === id;
}
```

Read more about [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

---

Working example:

```js
Vue.component('product-item', {
  template: `<button @click="passId">details</button>`,
  props: ['product'],
  methods: {
    passId() {
      this.$emit('select-product', this.product._id);
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    products: [
      { _id: 'one' },
      { _id: 'two' },
      { _id: 'three' }
    ]
  }),
  methods: {
    selectProduct(id) {
      console.log(this.products.find(p => p._id === id)?._id);
    }
  }
})
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14"></script>
<div id="app">
  <product-item
    v-for="product in products"
    :key="product._id"
    :product="product"
    @select-product="selectProduct" />
</div>
```

In the example above I changed a couple of names:

- `<ProductsList>` => `<ProductItem>`
- `selectedID` => `selectProduct`